# Two table join & count second tables column in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have two table one is states & another is cities tables. Now I want to join states tables state_id with cities tables state_id. Then I want to get states tables data with availables cities & count of that on the state. 
`NB:the query will be write with laravel query builder / eloquent` 
states table:

```
state_id| state_name 
--------+------------
 1      | state a
 2      | state b
 3      | state c
```

cities table :

```
city_id| city_name| state_id|
-------+------------+-----------+
 1     | city a| 1|
 2     | city b| 2|
 3     | city c| 1|
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = \App\Models\State::select('states.state_id', 'states.state_name', DB::raw("count(cities.id) as city_count"))
                                            ->leftjoin('cities', function($join){
                                                $join->on('states.state_id', '=', 'cities.state_id');
                                            })
                                            ->get();
```